# Solving for Unknown Radix

Tags: number-systems

If I have an equation like $$((34)_r + (24)_r) * (21)_r = (1480)_r$$How would I go about solving for r? Initially I tried to use the power series expansion to get the equation $$(5r + 8)(2r + 1) = r^3 + 4r^2 + 8r$$ but my answer comes out to be a decimal when the solution says r = 10. Any help?

Comment: Cannot be $r=10$. Just substitute in your former equality and verify that it does not hold.

Comment: Oh. I completely overlooked that. So is this question just nonsensical from the beginning? The context is that r should represent the total number of toes on an unusually intelligent chicken that proposed this equation.